# JavaScript Command pattern in popular frameworks or libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, ember.js

I'm reading 'Learning JavaScript design patterns' and chapter about Command pattern. Addy Osmani, the author gives an example of how it may be implemented: via `run()` or `execute()` methods to avoid coupling.

I jotted down at least two other examples that I came across:

- jQuery `.on()`
- jQuery UI factory plugin - and how it deals with method invocation, e.g `$('.some-object').myPlugin('myMethod')

Do you guys know other popular uses of that pattern in popular libraries or frameworks like Ember.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple use of `.apply()`, and I'm pretty sure it's used it most libraries or frameworks. There is also `.call()` that does something similar.

Here's the syntax:

```
myFunction.apply(receiver, arrayOfArgs)
myFunction.call(receiver, arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Where the "receiver" will be represented by `this` inside the function.

If you'd like to learn more I suggest you take a look at John Resig's book: [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://jsninja.com/)